# Handle Spring WebFlux WebClient timeout in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am doing a get http call with Spring WebFlux WebClient (Boot 2.4.3) in Kotlin (1.4.30). When request times out it fails with exception but instead I'd like to return a default value. I see references to `onError`, `onStatus` etc. used after `retrieve()` but they don't seem to be available in my case (only `body`, `toEntity`, `awaitExchange`)

The call:

```kotlin
suspend fun conversation(id: String): Conversation =
    client.get().uri("/conversation/{id}", id).retrieve().awaitBody()
```

WebClient configuration with connect and read timeouts:

```kotlin
fun webClient(url: String, connectTimeout: Int, readTimeout: Long, objectMapper: ObjectMapper): WebClient =
    WebClient.builder()
      .baseUrl(url)
      .exchangeStrategies(
        ExchangeStrategies.builder()
          .codecs { configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper)) }
          .build())
      .clientConnector(
        ReactorClientHttpConnector(
          HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
            .doOnConnected { connection ->
              connection.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            }))
      .build()
```

Response model:

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Conversation(
  val replyTimestamp: Map<String, String>,
)
```

How can I return default response (conversation with empty map) in case of timeout instead of failing with an exception?

Update:

I tried suggestion of JArgente below: updated the call with `awaitExchange` and set valid WireMock response with delay (1010 ms) that is longer that timeout (1000 ms).

Result is still ReadTimeoutException so looking at http status code does not help in this case.

```kotlin
  private val defaultConversation = Conversation(emptyMap())

  suspend fun conversation(id: String): Conversation =
    client.get()
      .uri("/conversation/{id}", id)
      .awaitExchange {
          response -> if (response.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)  response.awaitBody() else defaultConversation
      }
```

Response:

```json
{
  "replyTimestamp": {
    "1": "2021-02-23T15:30:28.753Z",
    "2": "2021-02-23T16:30:28.753Z"
  }
}
```

Mock config for it:

```
{
  "mappings":
  [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/conversation/1"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 1010,
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
        "bodyFileName": "conversation1.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As you use coroutines, you can simply use a try-catch to act on relevant exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Martin's suggestion ended up just wrapping call in a try/catch:

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <reified T : Any> WebClient.ResponseSpec.tryAwaitBodyOrElseLogged(default: T, log: Logger) : T =
  try {
    awaitBody()
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    log.warn("Remote request failed, returning default value ($default)", e)
    default
  }
```

```kotlin
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
private val default = Conversation(emptyMap())

suspend fun conversation(id: String): Conversation =
  client.get()
    .uri("/conversation/{id}", id)
    .retrieve()
    .tryAwaitBodyOrElseLogged(default, log)
```

I thought there is some idiomatic way but this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because in your method, you are expecting to get a response of type Conversation, but because you are receiving an error, the body is different.
The way you should handle the response, in this case, should be first, to look at the HTTP status code and then convert the body accordingly.
Here is an example from spring.io
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html

In your case, when you receive the status code of the error you should create a new empty Conversation and return it

```
val entity = client.get()
  .uri("/conversation/{id}", id)
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .awaitExchange {
        if (response.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
             return response.awaitBody<Conversation>()
        }
        else if (response.statusCode().is4xxClientError) {
             return response.awaitBody<ErrorContainer>()
        }
        else {
             throw response.createExceptionAndAwait()
        }
  }
```

Comment: Looking at status code does not help with timeouts. I updated the question with results of your suggestion.